# JavaFX label.getText() returns nothing

Tags: database, sqlite, javafx, controller

I have a project where I have two different controllers adminUserList and editStaffController, adminUserStaff is passing a string to editStaffController.

```
public void openStaffEdit(ActionEvent actionEvent, String form, boolean cW){

        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/home/editStaff.fxml"));

            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

            editStaffController eS = loader.getController();
            eS.setUsername(itemname);


            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();



            stage.show();
            // Hide this current window (if this is what you want)

            if(cW == true){
                ((Node)(actionEvent.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

and when it recieves the string its set in a label and in a field

```
 public void setUsername(String editUsername){
        username_lb.setText(editUsername);
        username_field.setText(editUsername);
    }
```

and it displays correctly in the program when I run it.

However, when I try to get the data in initialize it returns empty even tough the program is showing it in the field.

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        position_Box.getItems().addAll("Franchise", "Receptionist" , "Mechanic", "Foreperson");
        info_txt.setVisible(false);

        System.out.println(username_field.getText());
        setFields();
    }
```

Is there a way to fix this? Is there a better way to pass the data from the adminUserListController to editStaffController and save it in a variable?

Thanks in advance. If you have any questions about the code, feel free to ask.

Comment: Comparing booleans to `true` or `false` always irritates me. the same result can be achieved using the (possibly negated) boolean itself: `if (cW)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the username **after** the `initialize()` method is executed while loading the FXML document. So when you call `username_field.getText()`, it **is** empty.

Keep in mind that by the time your interface is displayed on the screen, your controller's constructor and the `initialize()` method have already completely finished running.

---

The code you posted does not include enough information to know what you're trying to accomplish, but you should not generally try to retrieve data from a node within the `initialize()` method. If you need access to the username in the `initialize()` method, declare a class field in your controller, which can be set by the constructor:

```
private String username;

public YourController(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

Now you just need to declare your controler in your Java code instead of in the FXML document and pass the username as a parameter:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/home/editStaff.fxml"));
loader.setController(new YourController(username));
```

---

Some assumptions are made since your code samples are not complete, but this should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zephyr. I used to think that because I called the method in other controller first, in the new controller initialize would run after the method. Now its working fine and I can get the variable.